# Live search on Laravel using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4, livesearch

I'm trying to do a live search in Laravel 5.4 and it's not working, the console shows error *GET http://localhost/bodegasilusion/public/search 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:9392*

I can't figure out why it's not working, when I overwrite the code and just console.log() the value of $search, it works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

MY CONTROLLER

```
public function tableSearch(Request $request){

    if ($request->ajax())
    {
        $output = "";
        $products = DB::table('products')
            ->where('code', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')->get();

        if ($products)
        {
            foreach($products as $key => $product){
                $output .=  '<tr class="gradeA odd" role="row">' .  
                                '<td class="text-center" data-id="{{ $product->id }}">'. $product->id .'</td>'.                          
                                '<td class="text-center">' . $product->code . '</td>'.
                                '<td class="displayImage" >' . '<img class="table_image" src="{{  route("product.image", ["image" => $product->image])  }}" alt="{{ $product->image }}">' . '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp' . $product->description . '</td>'.
                                '<td class="text-center">' . $product->in . '</td>'.
                                '<td class="text-center">' . $product->out . '</td>'.
                                '<td class="text-center">' . $product->in - $product->out . '</td>'.
                            '</tr>';   
            }

        }

        return Response($output);
    }
}
```

MY ROUTE

```
 Route::get('/search', [
    'uses' => 'ProductsController@tableSearch',
    'as' => 'search'
 ]);
```

MY SCRIPT

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#search").on('keyup', function(){
             $search = $(this).val();
             $.ajax({
                     type: 'get',
                     url: '{{ URL::to("search") }}',
                     data: {'search': $search},
                     success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                     }

              });
          });
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: Please paste the error. When you are getting the 500 error, you should also get some error info in the response. Make sure you have enabled log in your .env file.

Comment: I get the following errors in the log file

Comment: Where is the log? Please add into question.

Comment: did you find any answer ? i am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by looking at the log file, I confirmed I was not including the *use DB* in my class.